# Splitting a long unordered list into multiple lists

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm currently generated one `<ul>` with the following code:

```
function ListItem(props) {
  return <li>{props.value}</li>;
}

function ListLinks() {
  const listItems = footerLinks.map(section => {
    return section.data.map(({id, name, to}) => {
      return <ListItem key={id} value={name} />
    })
  });

  return listItems;
}
```

```
return (
  <ul>
    <ListLinks />
  </ul>
)

/* Output
<ul>
  <li>blah</li>
  <li>blah</li>
  …
</ul>
*/
```

However, I'd like to split the `<ul>` into multiple `<ul>`s. In the outer `map` in `ListLinks()`, I know that a new section is beginning. However, I'm not sure how to break the `JSX` up in a way to create `n` lists based on the number of sections.

Ultimately, I'm trying to create:

```html
<ul>
  <li>list 1 title</li>
  <li>list 1 item</li>
  …
</ul>

<ul>
  <li>list 2 title</li>
  <li>list 2 item</li>
  …
</ul>
```

Here is my input data.

```
const footerLinks = [{
  "title": "Learn More",
  "data": [{
      id: 'news',
      name: 'News',
      to: '/news'
    },
    {
      id: 'faq',
      name: 'FAQ',
      to: '/faq'
    }
  ]
},
{
  "title": "Media",
  "data": [{
      id: 'media',
      name: 'Media Kit',
      to: '/media'
    },
    {
      id: 'media_enquiries',
      name: 'Media Enquiries',
      to: '/media_enquiries'
    }
  ]
}]
```

Comment: Could you also post your input data?

Comment: @NenadVracar Updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add one more `map` call inside `ListLinks` component to create `ul` and `h4` title for each section.

```js
const footerLinks = [{"title":"Learn More","data":[{"id":"news","name":"News","to":"/news"},{"id":"faq","name":"FAQ","to":"/faq"}]},{"title":"Media","data":[{"id":"media","name":"Media Kit","to":"/media"},{"id":"media_enquiries","name":"Media Enquiries","to":"/media_enquiries"}]}]

function ListItem(props) {
  return <li>{props.value}</li>;
}

function ListLinks(props) {
  const listItems = props.data.map(section => (
    <div key={section.title}>
      <h4>{section.title}</h4>
      <ul>{section.data.map(item => (
       <ListItem key={item.id} value={item.name} />
      ))}</ul>
    </div>
  ));

  return listItems;
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <ListLinks data={footerLinks} />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
function ListLinks() {
   const listItems =footerLinks.map(section => {
   let x = section.data.map(({id, name, to}) => {
   return <ListItem key={id} value={name} />
   })
   return (<ul>{x}</ul>)
});

return listItems;
}
```

I have added the code in https://codesandbox.io/s/ko361j7wkv

Answer (score 0):

I am not really sure, but try the example of @ShantiswarupTunga, play with it, try this as well: `<ul><ListItem key={id} value={name} /></ul>`